# How to concat mail merge IF fields in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, mail-merge

I have Word 2013 and I have a need to display a piece of text only if a mail merge field equals 1.

Simple:

```
{ IF {MERGEFIELD Discount} = 1 "You get a discount" "You don't get a discount" }
```

However, I need to be able to include the discount given (since it'll vary widely), for example, if they are entitled to a discount, I might want it to say:

```
You get a discount of £<<discount_value>>
```

But I cannot for the life of me work out how to do it. Nothing I've seen online shows how to do it, I've tried using the concatenate method (like in Excel) but that doesnt work:

```
{ IF {MERGEFIELD Discount} = 1 CONCAT("You get a discount of £", {MERGEFEILD Discount_Value}) "You don't get a discount" }
```

Also, If I use the wizard to create an IF condition (then view it by Alt+F9) then it looks different to if I was to manually type in an IF condition. It also doesn't work if I manually type in the IF condition.

**Questions:**

1. How do I concatenate within an `IF` condition?
2. How can I manually write an IF condition without using Words wizard?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I just found the answer to both my questions:

It turns out that you cannot simply type a curly bracket `{` to use in mail merge. it has to be some kind of special curly bracket, which I found can be inserted by pressing `Ctrl+F9` (on windows).

Now I can manually type IF conditions.

To merge a string to a field simply use the `{MERGEFIELD some_field}` string in the enclosed quotes:

```
"You are entitled to a discount of £{MERGEFIELD Discount_Value}"
```